# Reloading a div using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm Using ajax to reload a specific div after the function is complete. It works fine but when it reloads it just gets behind a transparent black so I can just see it but can't click any thing
like this:
[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqrRH.png)
also the menu bar displays double after reloading:

```
$('#updateemployee').click(function(e) {
                    //sending the data gathered from input of user to php file where api is called

                    e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "php/updatePersonnelByID.php",
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType:'json',
                            
                            data: {
                                firstName: $('#fename').val(),
                                lastName:$('#lename').val(),
                                jobTitle:$('#Jetitle').val(),
                                email:$('#eemail').val(),
                                departmentID:$('#udept').val(),
                                id:$('#employeeid').val(),
                            },
                            //if user enters correct data and api gives back the data then we run success funtion
                            success: function(result) {
                    
                                console.log(result);
                    
                                //if status of data is ok we fetch the data from fields and put them in results table in html
                                if (result.status.name == "ok") {
                    
                                    //fetching fields from api and showing them in html table
                                  Swal.fire({
                                    title:"updated",
                                    text:"updated",
                                    type:"success"
                                  }).then(function(){
                                    $("#updateconfirmation").modal("hide");
                                    $("#editemployeemodal").modal("hide");
                                     $('#employeestable').load(location.href + "#employeestable>*")
                                     
                                  });
                                 
                                 
                    
                                }else{
                                    //if the upper condition  fails
                                    console.log("error");
                                   
                                }
                            
                            },
                            //if there is no success in retrieving data from api
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    
                                console.log("error");
                                $('#txterror').html("Enter Valid Id");
                            }
                        }); 
                    
                    });
```

I'm making this ajax request to update employee data its all working fine the problem is in Swal.fire part that when it reloads the div it just gets it behind a transparent black probably because some of the alert or modal is not closing properly please help

tried reloading a specific div and working fine but gets hide behind black transparent screen

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: Likely cause: `load(location.href + "#employeestable>*")` should be `load(location.href + " #employeestable")`  - with a space before the "#" so it's not part of the url.  Without the space, your `$("#employeestable")` will be loaded with the entire page, not just the fragment - and this would include the various modal backdrops, which is what your screenshot looks like.

Comment: Still not helping

Comment: Is it intentional that the header with "Employees | Departments | Locations" gets duplicated here, as can bee seen on your screenshot? If not, this is probably an indicator that you are inserting "too much", and thereby duplicating elements.

Comment: We don't know what the HTML / DOM structure you are inserting this into is, and we don't know what exactly it is you are inserting either. Questions like this should be asked with a proper [mre], and not just a snippet that shows us only part of the issue.

Comment: @CBroe that would happen if OP did `$("#id").load(url+"#id")` instead of `$("#id").load(url+" #id")``

Comment: Try `modal("show");` after you load the data. It seems like a css z-index issue.